# Getting "Finally is not a function" in bluebird, why?

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I have included Bluebird like so...

```
<script src="../../js/libs/bluebird.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I run the following code...

```
requestEvent(request, src)

        .then(function (response) {

            ...
        })
        .finally(function () {

            ...
        });

function requestEvent(request, src) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'mywebsite',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.status == 0) {

                    reject(response.message);
                }

                resolve(response);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                reject(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I get...

> TypeError: requestEvent(...).then(...).finally is not a function

Why does finally not exist?

This is client/browser code.

Comment: It feels that you didn't use `installation` section from the docs, and using native `Promise` on instead of bluebird. Have you done [this](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/install.html#browserify-and-webpack)?

Comment: I'm not using node.

Comment: Check your script path, I tested and it works fine, check this out https://jsbin.com/labixiwiru/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I have two pages and was testing it from the one without a script reference.

Comment: I'd suggest you delete your question since it is no longer on-topic for stack overflow and there is no reason for people to read and try to answer the question.  Deleting it will also avoid an accumulation of downvotes.

Comment: Not all browsers support the Promise.prototype.finally() method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Comment: need to add `const Promise = require("bluebird")` at top of code to use bluebird Promise instead of default one.

Comment: Do not delete this question, it was the top google hit and help resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

<del>`finally()` is not a function for a promise</del>

<del>Read this : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise</del>

You need to check if the path of bluebird is correct or not.

**Update 2018:** `.finally()` is *now* (TC39 stage 4; finished) part of the official specification now as you can see in the same link above or [in this specific page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally). However [not many browsers support it yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I'm trying to use Bluebird not native.

Comment: but in your code you're using native Promise and i replied to your question : Why does finally not exist?

Comment: So how do I use the Bluebird promise instead of native?

Comment: your tried somethin like this **var Promise = require("bluebird");**

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Why didn't you read the question more closely :P?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  The docs say that finally() is a function of Promise.prototype.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Comment: @LawrenceI.Siden yes true, i have updated the answer ;) as when posted finally was not a function of promise